# How to find string Initials in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following table:

| COL_1 | COL_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | J. Z. |
| 2 | T. M. Z. |
| 3 | Banana. Jacobs |
| 4 | I. |
| 5 | Busta Rhymes. |
| 6 | Jesus H. Christ |

How would I find strings that contain strings that contain initials of the format below:

- A.
- A. B.
- A. B. C.

I tried using like '%[A-Z.]%', but it returns me all of the strings that contain a dot. For example:

```
select * from table where COL_2 like '%[A-Z].%'
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate spaces to the searched column and include spaces in the search argument:

```
select * 
from table 
where concat(' ', COL_2, ' ') like '% [A-Z]. %';
```